# Invalidtooltips position is it possible?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have been searching for a way for my invalid tooltips to move to move a bit to the right to match my input position, but so far I don't have any luck. Here's the image:

[image]

Here's the code for this:

---

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for = "contact" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact:</label> 

<div class="col-4" id="contactContainer">
<div class="flex phone"style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<input style="margin-right: 10px; width: 200px;" id="validationcontact" name="contact" type="text" class="form-control" pattern="\b\d{8}\b" required >
<input type="button" class="ar add" value="Add More Field" style="cursor: pointer;">
<!-- <span class="ar add"><label style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 5px;"><i data-feather="plus" ></i></label></span> -->
<span class="ar remove"><label style="cursor: pointer; padding-top: 5px;"><i style="width: 20px; height: 20px; color: lightseagreen;"data-feather="x"></i></label></span>
<div class="invalid-tooltip">
    Enter a correct Contact!
</div>    
</div>

</div>
```

========================================================================
Does anyone know how invalid tooltips can move? I tried to do `padding-left` and `padding-right` it seems is increasing the button instead ?

Comment: Did you try `margin-left`? Or just `left`?

Comment: margin-left i tested

Comment: What about `left`?

Comment: ah yes i try left and margin it seems to be working now

Comment: got to wait like 6min i do it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try `margin-left` and `left` to bump it a bit, instead of padding.